# How can I matrix-multiply two PyTorch quantized Tensors?

Tags: pytorch, matrix-multiplication, quantization

I am new to tensor quantization, and tried doing something as simple as

```py
import torch
x = torch.rand(10, 3)
y = torch.rand(10, 3)

x@y.T
```

with PyTorch *quantized* tensors running on CPU. I thus tried

```py
scale, zero_point = 1e-4, 2
dtype = torch.qint32
qx = torch.quantize_per_tensor(x, scale, zero_point, dtype)
qy = torch.quantize_per_tensor(y, scale, zero_point, dtype)

qx@qy.T # I tried...
```

..and got as error

> RuntimeError: Could not run 'aten::mm' with arguments from the
> 'QuantizedCPUTensorId' backend. 'aten::mm' is only available for these
> backends: [CUDATensorId, SparseCPUTensorId, VariableTensorId,
> CPUTensorId, SparseCUDATensorId].

Is matrix multiplication just not supported, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5):

It is not straight forward to implement matrix multiplication for quantized matrices. Therefore, the "conventional" matrix multiplication (`@`) does not support it (as your error message suggests).

You should look at quantized operations, e.g., [`torch.nn.quantized.functional.linear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/quantization.html#torch.nn.quantized.functional.linear):

```py
torch.nn.quantized.functional.linear(qx[None,...], qy.T)
```